# SSRS expression to calculate total based on daily counts that have conditions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016

In a totals row (location is row group, date is the column group), I'm not sure how to calculate a total based on the below expression that I've been using to calculate "overcapacity" daily totals.  I'm trying to total up the daily overcap counts.

The below expression works fine when grouped under the "date" column grouping.  So each day in the range picked by the user displays with an "overcapacity" count (if the visitscounts > 7, then the result is visitscounts - 7, otherwise it is 0).

But I'm not sure how to total up the resultant overcapacity counts (I can total up visitcounts fine). The issue is that it takes the FULL daily count and THEN applies the -7, instead of just summing all the previously calculated daily counts (if the daily account exceeds 7, then it subtracts 7 from the full daily count, to come up with an "overcapacity" count).

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4",Fields!VisitsCount.Value,0)) > 7,

SUM(SUM(IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4",Fields!VisitsCount.Value,0))-7),

0)
```

### [image]

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

**Dataset Query:**

```
SELECT 
    L.Location
  , D.[date]
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(V.VisitID AS VARCHAR(10))+V.Location+V.[Room-Bed]) AS VisitsCount
FROM dbo.DateTable(@StartDate, @EndDate) AS D  
     CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2) 
    AS L LEFT JOIN  dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2 AS V ON D.[date]      BETWEEN 
    V.EffectiveDate AND ISNULL(V.ServiceEndDate, @EndDate)                      AND V.Location = L.Location
WHERE V.EffectiveDate IS NULL OR
      (V.EffectiveDate <= @EndDate OR
      V.ServiceEndDate >= @StartDate OR
      V.ServiceEndDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
      L.Location
      , D.[date]
ORDER BY L.Location, D.[date]
```

---

### OverCap New Column Testing

**Dataset Query with Added OverCap Column:**

```
SELECT 
      x.Location
     , x.[date]
     , x.VisitsCount
    , OverCap = IIF(VisitsCount-7 <0 ,0, VisitsCount-7)
    FROM (
            SELECT 
            L.Location
            , D.[date]
            , COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(V.VisitID AS VARCHAR(10))+V.Location+V.[Room-Bed]) AS VisitsCount
            FROM dbo.DateTable(@StartDate, @EndDate) AS D  
            CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2) 
            AS L LEFT JOIN  dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2 AS V ON D.[date]      BETWEEN 
            V.EffectiveDate AND ISNULL(V.ServiceEndDate, @EndDate)                      AND V.Location = L.Location
            WHERE V.EffectiveDate IS NULL OR
                  (V.EffectiveDate <= @EndDate OR
                  V.ServiceEndDate >= @StartDate OR
                  V.ServiceEndDate IS NULL)
            GROUP BY 
                  L.Location
                  , D.[date]
            ) x
      ORDER BY x.Location, x.[date]
```

**Full Report Layout with OverCap added**
Grouped by Location (row) and [date] (column), with a totals row outside row group for combined location.

[report layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF1nw.png)

**Current Resultset with OverCap Column**

[CurrentResultSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kGgL.png)

***NOTES:***

Result for LOC3-4 is **129** (see CurrentResultSet) if I use:

```
OverCap = IIF(VisitsCount-7 <0 ,0, VisitsCount-7)
```

Result for LOC3-4 is **34** if I use:

```
OverCap = IIF(Location = 'LOC3' OR Location = 'LOC4', VisitsCount,0)
```

Result for LOC3-4 is **24** if I use:

```
OverCap = IIF((Location = 'LOC3' OR Location = 'LOC4') AND VisitsCount > 7, VisitsCount,0)
```

**Expressions Used Successfully for GROUPED locations:**

DailyVisitorCount (used for both DailyVisitorCount and TotalVisitorCount).

```
=Sum(Fields!VisitsCount.Value)
```

DailyOverCapacityCount (used for both DailyOverCapacityCount and TotalOverCapacityCount):

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC1" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 24, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 24), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC2" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 16, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 16), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 7, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 7), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 7, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 7),
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC5" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 11, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 11),  
   True, 0)
```

Averages were calculated by using the above expressions but adding to the end:

```
/CountDistinct(Fields!date.Value)
```

**Expressions Used for combined location (outside grouped location row)**

DailyVisitorCount (used successfully for both DailyVisitorCount and TotalVisitorCount).

```
=IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4", Sum(Fields!VisitsCount.Value), 0)
```

TotalOverCapCount (used successfully with DAILY TotalOverCapCount, but not the Total TotalOverCapCount

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4",Fields!VisitsCount.Value,0)) > 7,
SUM(SUM(IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4",Fields!VisitsCount.Value,0))-7),
0)
```

**Expressions still needed:**

- Total TotalOverCapCount (adds up daily totals for the duration)
- Average TotalOverCapCount (average of daily totals for the duration)

Comment: I *think* I know how to solve this but it would be easier if you supplied some sample data that will reproduce the results you have shown here.  The sample data should be same structure as the data that gets returned from your dataset query.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I wasn't sure how best to give you the dataset sample -- I saved it as a CSV file and shared it out from my Google Docs.  If you'd like a different format/different download site, let me know.  This data is from Oct 31-Nov 2, to keep consistent with my results screenshot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFIDRYv6C73nNM9qevxI-tNnbZGJw5KO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the data from your dataset. Your expression refers to a field called VisitsCount which is not in the data you supplied so I gues you have a dataset query that process this data ready for the report. It's the out from the dataset query I need.

Comment: Ah!  Sorry about that -- that was the data I was using to verify the count was correct.  I uploaded the proper version with the count (VisitsCount) instead of the VisitIDs.  Same link as before

Answer (score 0):

As the expression you are trying to sum requires two scoped expression parts, it's actually difficult to then sum these.

What you need to do is

```
=SUM(
     SUM(Fields!.MyField.Value, "ColumnGroup")
     , "RowGroup")
```

This is *probably* not possible in your scenario. I abandoned the approach quickly and just updated the dataset query to return the data I needed instead

So the dataset query looked like this (using you sample data)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE([Location] varchar(10), [Date] Date, [VisitsCount] int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('LOC1', '2022-10-31', 18),    ('LOC1', '2022-11-01', 19),
('LOC1', '2022-11-02', 19),    ('LOC2', '2022-10-31', 34),
('LOC2', '2022-11-01', 30),    ('LOC2', '2022-11-02', 35),
('LOC3', '2022-10-31', 8),    ('LOC3', '2022-11-01', 8),
('LOC3', '2022-11-02', 8),    ('LOC4', '2022-10-31', 5),
('LOC4', '2022-11-01', 5),    ('LOC4', '2022-11-02', 7),
('LOC5', '2022-10-31', 11),    ('LOC5', '2022-11-01', 11),
('LOC5', '2022-11-02', 11)

SELECT 
    [Location], [Date], VisitsCount
    , OverCap = IIF(VisitsCount-7 <0 ,0, VisitsCount-7)
    FROM @t
```

As you can see, I added an `OverCap` column. Now all we need to do is sum that in the report.

The report design looks like this..

[image]

and the final report looks like this...

[image]

Obviously you might need to adapt this to suit whatever grouping you have going but I think it's probably a much simpler approach.

---

Edit after update by OP

---

You can wrap your original query in a SELECT and then move the order clause of of the sub query. That should give you the same results.

```
SELECT 
      [Location], [Date], VisitsCount
    , OverCap = IIF(VisitsCount-7 <0 ,0, VisitsCount-7)
    FROM (
            SELECT 
            L.Location
            , D.[date]
            , COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(V.VisitID AS VARCHAR(10))+V.Location+V.[Room-Bed]) AS VisitsCount
            FROM dbo.DateTable(@StartDate, @EndDate) AS D  
            CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2) 
            AS L LEFT JOIN  dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2 AS V ON D.[date]      BETWEEN 
            V.EffectiveDate AND ISNULL(V.ServiceEndDate, @EndDate)                      AND V.Location = L.Location
            WHERE V.EffectiveDate IS NULL OR
                  (V.EffectiveDate <= @EndDate OR
                  V.ServiceEndDate >= @StartDate OR
                  V.ServiceEndDate IS NULL)
            GROUP BY 
                  L.Location
                  , D.[date]
            ) x
      ORDER BY [Location], [date]
```

**If you want to just get LOC3+4 at the end of the table**

Then you can do this in SQL. All I've done here is taken the existing query, dumped the results to a temp table , then returned the results plus an extra row that only contains LOC3 and LOC4 data.

*Note: I added a GroupOrder column so you can sort on this in the report to make sure the combined row appears at the end.*

```
    SELECT 
          [Location], [Date], VisitsCount
        , OverCap = IIF(VisitsCount-7 <0 ,0, VisitsCount-7)
        INTO #t
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                L.Location
                , D.[date]
                , COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(V.VisitID AS VARCHAR(10))+V.Location+V.[Room-Bed]) AS VisitsCount
                FROM dbo.DateTable(@StartDate, @EndDate) AS D  
                CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2) 
                AS L LEFT JOIN  dbo.vHIMOverFlowBedReport2 AS V ON D.[date]      BETWEEN 
                V.EffectiveDate AND ISNULL(V.ServiceEndDate, @EndDate)                      AND V.Location = L.Location
                WHERE V.EffectiveDate IS NULL OR
                      (V.EffectiveDate <= @EndDate OR
                      V.ServiceEndDate >= @StartDate OR
                      V.ServiceEndDate IS NULL)
                GROUP BY 
                      L.Location
                      , D.[date]
                ) x


SELECT 
      GroupOrder = 1
      , [Location], [Date], VisitsCount, OverCap
      FROM #t 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
      GroupOrder = 2
      , [Location] = 'LOC3+4', MIN([Date]), SUM(VisitsCount), SUM(OverCap)
      FROM #t 
      WHERE [Location] IN ('LOC3', 'LOC4')
      GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
```

Comment: So, getting a little more complicated.... I actually already group the non-combined columns by row (location) and column (date).  Each location has a different condition for the overflow calculation (some are > 7, > 12, etc).  The totals that are part of the location grouping (individual locations) calculate fine using a Switch with conditions.  It's just the combined row, which I had to put below outside row group because my database doesn't have a location that combines the two, so that was the only way I could think of getting the information. WIll read more when home from work. Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding a column and it wouldn't accept it (probably because VisitsCount is created by a Count in the select statement, which you woudln't have known).  I posted my data query at the bottom of the original question, so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully get the query with the OverCap column included

Comment: I was able to create the OverCap column, but for the combined location, I still get the same results for Overcap Total (34 instead of 20) -- probably because it's still not part of the grouped locations.  I'm thinking what I need to do is find a way to create a new temporary "combined" location in the query, fill it with loc3 and 4 data, so then I can row group it with the other locations. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Post what your dataset results look like now after all the changes and I'll take another look when I get chance (probably Monday). Also explain your are grouping locations (part of your query, with row group expressions etc) so I can replicate.

Comment: All the information is now under the header "OverCap New Column Testing".  The report layout shows I grouped by location (row) and date (column), but the combined location is outside the row group because it's not a location in the database.  I tried different conditions for the OverCap column and noted the results for each. Depending on the conditions, I get 129, 34, or 24 (I included conditions I tested in a list). Not the expected '20'. I also listed the expressions I'm using, including a switch statement that lists overcapacity conditions for each location.

Comment: Still no luck with the column.  I went back to the old structure and tried =Sum(ReportItems!Textbox20.Value) which I thought (based on reading) would grab the results from the problem date cell after they were calculated and add them up, but that just gave me an aggregate error.  Tried going back to sql and making a stored procedure using a table-valued parameter to make a new combined location, but SSRS doesn't allow table-valued parameters apparently, so I'm very close to giving up.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you, it's really busy for me at the moment. I'm still not sure exactly what the problem is, if it's just getting LOC3 and LOC4 together then can't you just group them in SQL and UNION the results to the original query? I'll edit the answer to show this,

Comment: No worries -- I just told them they'd have to manually calculate that part.  The actual SQL view *was* a series of unions, including one that combined the two locations, but combining them in the union didn't help because the row group in SSRS still separates them out as different locations since there is no combined single location in the database.  That's why I tried to create a new location using a stored procedure with a TVP, but SSRS doesn't support TVPs apparently, so yeah... I have officially given up.